# An easy question about Google Maps - centering

Tags: javascript, html, url, maps

Every time I embed an iframe from Google Maps it keeps the marker in the middle.

And it does even if there's a tooltip and just CUTS the tooltip data:

http://jsfiddle.net/V2SVa/

Are there url parameters or something to center the map on the tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are using the API, then you can issue a call to [map.setCenter()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.setCenter).

If however you are including the maps inline as in your example, then you just need to change the initial starting point.

The URL you are using to embed the map is:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=
  &amp;q=Museum+near+Washington,+United+States&amp;aq=0
  &amp;sll=40.702863,-74.055748&amp;sspn=0.025669,0.055747&amp;ie=UTF8
  &amp;hq=Museum&amp;hnear=Washington+D.C.,+District+of+Columbia
  &amp;ll=38.913976,-77.05111&amp;spn=0.052698,0.111494&amp;t=h&amp;z=14
  &amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=4718114823360363843&amp;output=embed
```

Just a matter of adjusting certain parameters.

The parameters you need to adjust are `ll = center location`, `z = zoom level` and `spn/sspn = span / screen span`.  Surprisingly awkward to find information on them, but there is some details on the [parameters here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters).  Try fiddling with the `ll` parameter first if you need to change just the centre.

Comment: wow, thank you, it's too complicated anyways. I forgot to mention that my maps will be generated on the fly so I can't just adjust the parameters just for one case. If it's like that then I'm going for gmap plugin for jQuery :)

Comment: @anonymous: I thought you were restricted to using the embedding technique as that's what your demo showed.  The best method is just to use the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) directly, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

HTML

```
<div style="height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
  <iframe width="425" height="700" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Museum+near+Washington,+United+States&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=40.702863,-74.055748&amp;sspn=0.025669,0.055747&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Museum&amp;hnear=Washington+D.C.,+District+of+Columbia&amp;ll=38.913976,-77.05111&amp;spn=0.052698,0.111494&amp;t=h&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=4718114823360363843&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

JQUERY (not even necessary)

```
$("iframe").load(function (){
  $('iframe').css({"height": '400px'});
});
```

Demo: http://tinker.io/9ace5